# how to split text by comma the followed by space and not followed by number after the space?

Tags: python, sql, regex

Hi all I am trying to split a DDL by comma (in python3) but the problem is the data types like 'numeric(1,1)' or 'decimal(2, 4)' or even 'identity(1,2)' are giving me a hard time.

This is the input:

```
['x int not null, y decimal(2, 4) null, z numeric(7, 3), m bigint identity(1,1), d date]
```

This is what I want as output:

```
['x int not null','y decimal(2, 4) null','z numeric(7, 3)','m bigint identity(1,1)','d date']
```

Then I am splitting that by space and can work on my code.

If I use `list.split(',')` it also splits by the decimal comma and the identity..

edit: after problem with comma was solved I have different issue
Hi, I have this list:
['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7, 3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']

and I want to get this output for each iteration in mo for loop:
['x','int','not','null']
['y' ,'decimal(2, 4)', 'null']
etc...

when I am splitting that by space I get:
['x','int','not','null']
['y', 'decimal(2,','4)','null']

I do that because I want to work on list_after_split[1] that is the data type but I want to catch all numeric(2, 4) as one cell and not as 'decimal(2' and '4)'

how to split by a space that not followed by a number?

Comment: Hi, I have this list:
['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7, 3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']

and I want to get this output for each iteration in mo for loop:
['x','int','not','null']
['y' ,'decimal(2, 4)', 'null']
etc...

when I am splitting that by space I get:
['x','int','not','null']
['y', 'decimal(2,','4)','null']

i do that beacuse i eant to work on list_after_split[1] that is the data type but i want to catch all numeric(2, 4) as one cell and not as 'decimal(2' and '4)'

how to split by a space that not followed by a number?

Comment: Is that meant to be a comment to my answer?

Comment: yes paolo you right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use regex for this purpose, I beleieve something like this should work:

```
import re
my_list = ['x int not null, y decimal(2, 4) null, z numeric(7, 3), m bigint identity(1,1), d date']
result = re.split(r',\s*(?![^()]*\))', my_list[0])
# result => ['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7, 3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']
```

It will use "negative lookahead" to match all `,` characters which are not in parenthesis.

Once you get your results, loop through them and process them in any way you need:

```
for item in result:
    # split items more if needed:
    res = re.split(r' \s*(?![^()]*\))', item)
    print(res)
```

Comment: great! now i have another problem..
after i get this list i want to split by a space.. ['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7,  3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']
and if i have after hte number in numeric a space its aplit that also.. i want to avoid from splitting this kind of cases numeric'(2, 4)'.. how can i do that?

Comment: @Pythonist I updated my answer, but if this (or other answer) solves your current problem, please accept one of the answers which you find the most useful. As for "other problem", either try to solve it yourself or ask another question!

Comment: i will ask another question

Comment: Hi, I have this list:
['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7, 3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']

and I want to get this output for each iteration in mo for loop:
['x','int','not','null']
['y' ,'decimal(2, 4)', 'null']
etc...

when I am splitting that by space I get:
['x','int','not','null']
['y', 'decimal(2,','4)','null']

i do that beacuse i eant to work on list_after_split[1] that is the data type but i want to catch all numeric(2, 4) as one cell and not as 'decimal(2' and '4)'

how to split by a space that not followed by a number?

Comment: @Pythonist I updated my answer, check if that solves your problem. Also, please avoid updating original question with additional requirements, if a specific problem is solved, use check mark (✓) next to the answer which was helpful to accept it as solution. In case you will have additional problems after initial problem was solved, feel free to create a new question instead of updating the original one.

Answer (score 3):

Split on a comma followed by a space, not followed by a number and `)`:

```
>>> i = ['x int not null, y decimal(2, 4) null, z numeric(7, 3), m bigint identity(1,1), d date']
>>> o = re.split(r', (?![0-9]\))',''.join(i))
['x int not null', 'y decimal(2, 4) null', 'z numeric(7, 3)', 'm bigint identity(1,1)', 'd date']
```